# Selecting the "previous record" in a SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, select, where-clause

I am using the following code to access the previous record in a table,

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM newcarDB WHERE rowid < " +iCurrentRowid+ " ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1",null);
```

I will need to configure this so that when I get to the top of the table, (rowid = 1) the query stops. Previously I have done using a conditional so if rowid = 1, then return(). The problem is that if the record at rowid = 1 has been deleted and the top row has a rowid of 2, then my query has a problem and my application crashes.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: What does "previous record" mean?  You shouldn't be using rowid for this.  Datestamp maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to solve this?

Before accessing any data in the cursor, make sure it points to a valid row. Check the return value of your `moveTo...()` call on the cursor and only if it's `true`, access cursor data with `get...()` methods.